# How to dynamically add text to title when mouse is over?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have map with poly areas, lots off them and every area has title when my mouse pointer is over. How to dynamically add text to title ?
Can I fetch title before show by default and append new text ?

Explanation:

Add to hardcoded title inside html new random text.

Comment: You should share your html + JS code.

Comment: jquery can do that with the attr command.

Comment: By `title` you mean a `title` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the `title` attribute. You can change it dynamically this way:

```
$('div').hover(function () {
    this.title = 'new title';
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/A2CJu/)

However, if you are modifying the `title` while it's already shown by the browser, you will notice that the tooltip message will not update. I have tried different ways including swapping the current element with a cloned element (that has a different title) and programmatically trigger mouse events but it's seems there's no way to make it refresh.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.class_of_title').hover( function(){
   $(this).append('added title');
});
```

**Probably you are looking for [Hover Jquery Function](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)**

Comment: It will keep appending on every hover, you might want to fetch the text of attribute and append title and use .html()

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS pseudoelement

```
.myDiv {
//whatever
}

.myDiv:hover:after {
  content: "some added text";
  display: inline-block;
}
```